# In which folder is the Phonegap Config file located?

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile, cordova, splash-screen

Where on Phonegap Project in Eclipse IDE do I save the config.xml file?

```
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.phonegap.example"
    versionCode="10" <!-- optional: Android only -->
    version   = "1.0.0">

<name>PhoneGap Example</name>

<description>
    An example for phonegap build docs. 
</description>

<author href="https://build.phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
    Hardeep Shoker 
</author>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to save your config.xml file in project in eclipse.
Instead of that, you just need to upload that file, together with html and javascript files, to [here](https://build.phonegap.com/).